# How to find tagged questions?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

Earlier it was possible to see the list of tagged questions at the tag's page, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchdb

Now all of these questions shows no questions:

[image]

Is there a way to find these questions anywhere else?

**UPDATE**:

It seems that none of tabs are selected:

[image]

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: that's why the screenshot is attached

Comment: No repro here, I'm afraid. What were you doing at the time?

Comment: Are you on the *newest* tab?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: In your screenshot you see *unanswered*. Left to that is a *newest* tab. Click on it

Comment: @juergend [tag:couchdb] has questions on all tabs. That's not the problem here.

Comment: @michaelb958: No featured questions

Comment: @juergend That might do it; I don't see a 'featured' tab. Edit: **Repro!**

Comment: That is no bug. If there are no featured questions for that tag then the tab is not there

Comment: Hmmmm... I can select NEWEST manually and than it works as expected. It seems that by default none of tabs is selected so i see zero results.

Comment: I have added a screenshot, it should give a better picture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you were on the *featured* tab somewhere and go to a specific tag then the *featured* tab of that tag will be opened.

If there are no featured questions for that tag then you see no questions. Unfortunately the *featured* tab won't show too and no tab seems to be selected.

Steps to reproduce:

- Visist the *Stack Overflow* main site
- Click the *featured* tab
- Put the tag in your search query [tag-name] or click on the tag
- Now you see no questions if the tag contains no featured questions

Comment: Good idea, it gives a direction. But there are no selected tabs by default, can not mark as an exact answer

Comment: @Antonio - We save your last opened tab as default. So if you open http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ it will show your last opened tab by default.

Comment: I see. I have just tested and it works indeed when i enter tag page again. I have no clue how I managed to lost this "last selection"